# How to label Q1, median,Q3 and outliers in box plot in R

Tags: r, boxplot

Hello this might seem like a really simple question but I am a complete beginner and needed some guidance. Suppose I have a data set in a vector

```
mydata <- c(154,109,137,115,152,140,154,178,101,103,126,126,137,165,165,129,200,148)
```

and I want to create a box plot which I have created using

```
boxplot(mydata,main = "SSHA Data",horizontal = TRUE,staplewex = 1, xlab = "Scores")
```

But it just draws a box plot and displays the overall shape with no distinct values. If there is a way I would like to label the Q1, Q3, median value, and even the outlier if possible **on the boxplot itself**.  I will attach what I have for your reference.

[Boxplot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVc2E.png)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
# Create a vector.
mydata <- c(154,109,137,115,152,140,154,178,101,103,126,126,137,165,165,129,200,148)

# Create a boxplot with that data.
boxplot(mydata, main = "SSHA Data", horizontal = TRUE, staplewex = 1, xlab = "Scores")

# Add text.
text(x = boxplot.stats(mydata)$stats, labels = boxplot.stats(mydata)$stats, y = 1.25)


# If you also want to label the max value (the outlier)...
text(x = c(boxplot.stats(mydata)$stats, max(mydata)), labels = c(boxplot.stats(mydata)$stats, max(mydata)), y = 1.25)
```